# Bootstrap 5: How to make column widths flexible but still fill the row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 5, how do I make the columns have flexible widths based on their content, but all the columns still fill the full width of the row?

If I use `<div class="col">` the columns all have the same width. And if I use `<div class="col-auto">` the columns don't fill the width of the row.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the content?

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`flex-fill`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/#fill) class

```css
.row,.row>div {border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="flex-fill m-1" > a few  more text content</div>
    <div class="flex-fill m-1" > Some text content</div>
    <div class="flex-fill m-1" > text content</div>
    <div class="flex-fill m-1" > little</div>
    <div class="flex-fill m-1" > some content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It will also alow you to easily set a margin or a gap. If you do not want wrapping on small screen , use `flex-nowrap` on the row container.